Manhua where the main character transmigrates to game-like world where he quickly becomes strong then kills a boss like character
Manhua where the main character transmigrates to a game-like world where he quickly becomes strong. He kills a boss like character, then kills 4-5 people who come to clear that world, but they get killed by the main character. Then the main character gets a system to transmigrate to other worlds. The main character saves girls and later has the ability to keep them in a separate space where many girls live.

I found it. It is I am the King.

In order to return to his hometown, the Earth, Gao Miao the traverser, journeys through the IP worlds of novels, comics, movies, etc. Experiencing a variety of different lives, getting to know a bunch of beautiful women, and beating up strong enemies.


Glad you found it. In future, though, please don't post links to piracy sites here. When posting answers to manga/manhwa/manhua story-ID questions, it is better to link to sites such as Anime-Planet, MyAnimeList, or Baka-Updates.

Also, we'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. However, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.
